# what is android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x39?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi i am getting Resources$NotFoundException. I have tried many ways but i coudnt able find my mistake. I am new to android.Kindly come up with the solution.Here is my code. I am using recyclerview adapter to set values from json.

```
public class AnalyticAssessAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnalyticAssessAdapter.Holder> {
private Context context;
private int userID;
private List<AnalyticModel> arraList;

public AnalyticAssessAdapter(Context context, int userID, List<AnalyticModel> arraList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userID = userID;
    this.arraList = arraList;
}

@Override
public AnalyticAssessAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_analytical_assess, parent, false);
    Holder holder = new Holder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, final int position) {

    holder.testNum.setText(arraList.get(position).getTest_id());
    holder.testCategory.setText(arraList.get(position).getCategory_id());
    holder.mark.setText(arraList.get(position).getTestscore());
    holder.topScore.setText(arraList.get(position).getHighscore());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arraList.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView testNum;
    TextView testCategory;
    TextView testDate;
    TextView mark;
    TextView topScore;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.testNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_no_aa);
        this.testCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_name_aa);
        this.testDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_date_aa);
        this.mark = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mark_aa);
        this.topScore = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.top_score_aa);

    }
}
```

}

Here is my exception.

FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.admin.crackanalytics, PID: 15972
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x39
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:312)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:52)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4422)
    at com.admin.crackanalytics.view.adapter.AnalyticAssessAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AnalyticAssessAdapter.java:45)
    at com.admin.crackanalytics.view.adapter.AnalyticAssessAdapter.onBindViewHolder(AnalyticAssessAdapter.java:21)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5094)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2843)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5954)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18804)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2112)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl
```

Comment: please check resources that you created like (layouts and textviews) and theirs id's like(adapter_analytical_assess, adapter_analytical_assess) are correct or not. And if they are correct then clean your project and build it again.

Comment: Everything seems fine. But still i am getting that exception.

Comment: It should return holder but not view. I tried but not working @DeepakSachdeva

Comment: @Bakya post your adapter_analytical_assess.xml file.

Comment: @Bakya can you AnalyticModel class file

Comment: Found the mistake. Here i was trying to set int value to string. Thanks for all your help